# Implementing Hierarchy in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table which has a "CDATE" representing the date when I retrieved the data, a "SECID" identifying the security I retrieved data for, a "SOURCE" designating where I got the data and the "VALUE" which I got from the source. My data might look as following:

```
CDATE   | SECID | SOURCE | VALUE
--------------------------------
1/1/2012    1       1        23
1/1/2012    1       5        45
1/1/2012    1       3        33
1/4/2012    2       5        55
1/5/2012    1       5        54
1/5/2012    1       3        99
```

Suppose I have a HIERARCHY table like the following ("SOURCE" with greatest HIERARCHY number takes precedence):

```
SOURCE  |  NAME | HIERARCHY
---------------------------
  1        ABC       10
  3        DEF        5
  5        GHI        2
```

Now let's suppose I want my results to be picked according to the hierarchy above. So applying the hierarch and selecting the source with the greatest HIERARCHY number I would like to end up with the following:

```
 CDATE   | SECID | SOURCE | VALUE
---------------------------------
1/1/2012    1       1        23
1/4/2012    2       5        55
1/5/2012    1       3        99
```

Comment: You just missing your sort by hierarchy desc?

Comment: Also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx for hierarchyid in sql 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This joins on your hierarchy and selects the top-ranked source for each date and security.

```
SELECT CDATE, SECID, SOURCE, VALUE
FROM (
  SELECT t.CDATE, t.SECID, t.SOURCE, t.VALUE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CDATE, t.SECID
                       ORDER BY h.HIERARCHY DESC) as nRow
  FROM table1 t
  INNER JOIN table2 h ON h.SOURCE = t.SOURCE
) A
WHERE nRow = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the results you want with the below.  It combines your data with your hierarchies and ranks them according to the highest hierarchy.  This will only return one result arbitrarily though if you have a source repeated for the same date.

```
;with rankMyData as (
    select
        d.CDATE
    ,   d.SECID
    ,   d.SOURCE
    ,   d.VALUE
    ,   row_number() over(partition by d.CDate, d.SECID order by h.HIERARCHY desc) as ranking
    from DATA d
      inner join HIERARCHY h
        on h.source = d.source
)
SELECT
    CDATE
,   SECID
,   SOURCE
,   VALUE
FROM rankMyData
where ranking = 1
```

Comment: probably should partition by CDATE and SECID

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  Was a little ambiguous from the original question.